# TabView on Nativescript-Angular crashing iOs app

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm building an app using nativescript-angular. When running on Android, everything works great. When running on iOs, the app crashes when trying to render a TabView. I can't find anything about this error. Does any body have any ideas?

Here is the error:

```
***** Fatal JavaScript exception - application has been terminated. *****
NativeScript encountered a fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of null
at
_updateIOSTabBarColorsAndFonts(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/tab-view/index.ios.js:444:23)
at [fontInternal:setNative](file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/tab-view/index.ios.js:494:0)
at applyPendingNativeSetters(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/properties/index.js:1059:0)
at initNativeView(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/properties/index.js:1018:0). 
at onResumeNativeUpdates(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:695:22)
at _resumeNativeUpdates(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:259:0)
at onLoaded(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:214:0)
at onLoaded(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/tab-view/index.ios.js:268:0)
at (file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:297:0)
at callFunctionWithSuper(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:291:0)
at callLoaded(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:297:0)
at loadView(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:437:0)
at (file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:216:0)
at eachChildView(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js:101:0)
at eachChild(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-common.js:700:0)
at onLoaded(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:215:0)
at (file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:297:0)
at callFunctionWithSuper(file:///app/vendor.js:11791
```

I'm using tns version 7.2.0

```
tns --version
7.2.0
```

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "@nativescript/template-hello-world-ng",
  "main": "main.js",
  "version": "7.0.8",
  "author": "NativeScript Team <oss@nativescript.org>",
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "nativescript",
    "mobile",
    "angular",
    "{N}",
    "template"
  ],
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.0",
    "@nativescript/angular": "10.0.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "^7.2.1",
    "@nativescript/firebase": "^11.1.3",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.0",
    "nativescript-carousel": "^7.0.1",
    "nativescript-fontawesome": "^1.0.0",
    "nativescript-ngx-fonticon": "^7.0.0",
    "nativescript-ui-dataform": "^7.0.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.6",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.0",
    "@nativescript/android": "7.0.1",
    "@nativescript/ios": "7.2.0",
    "@nativescript/types": "~7.0.0",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~3.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~11.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  },
  "gitHead": "41a7254d3bc134fd3c258761f3c6e1c3d54e6d41",
  "private": "true",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Apprently TabView is depreciated as of Nativescript 6. I used BottomNavigation instead.